# Database Disk Queue too high, what can be done?

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2000, ado

I have a problem with a large database I am working with which resides on a single drive - this Database contains around a dozen tables with the two main ones are around 1GB each which cannot be made smaller.  My problem is the disk queue for the database drive is around 96% to 100% even when the website that uses the DB is idle. What optimisation could be done or what is the source of the problem the DB on Disk is 16GB in total and almost all the data is required - transactions data, customer information and stock details.
What are the reasons why the disk queue is always high no matter the website traffic?
What can be done to help improve performance on a database this size?

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

The database is an MS SQL 2000 Database running on Windows Server 2003 and as stated 16GB in size (Data File on Disk size).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, how much memory do you have on the machine?  If you can't store the pages in memory, SQL Server is going to have to go to the disk to get it's information.  If your memory is low, you might want to consider upgrading it.

Since the database is so big, you might want to consider adding two separate physical drives and then putting the transaction log on one drive and partitioning some of the other tables onto the other drive (you have to do some analysis to see what the best split between tables is).

In doing this, you are allowing IO accesses to occur in parallel, instead of in serial, which should give you some more performance from your DB.

Comment: Managed to find some ways of reducing disk queue with some old data that was in the DB, tables on other drives sounds interesting too, if performance overhead is not greater than any gain from doing this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Before buying more disks and shifting things around, you might also update statistics and check your queries - if you are doing lots of table scans and so forth you will be creating unnecessary work for the hardware.

Your database isn't that big after all - I'd first look at tuning your queries.  Have you profiled what sort of queries are hitting the database?

Answer (score 1):

If you disk activity is that high while your site is idle, I would look for other processes that might be running that could be affecting it.  For example, are you sure there aren't any scheduled backups running?  Especially with a large db, these could be running for a long time.

As Mike W pointed out, there is usually a lot you can do with query optimization with existing hardware.  Isolate your slow-running queries and find ways to optimize them first.  In one of our applications, we spent literally 2 months doing this and managed to improve the performance of the application, and the hardware utilization, dramatically.